# Color on hover in css

Tags: html, css

I want the color to change when I hover the button (button only) but it didn't work.
Here is what I've tried so far;

```
.third {
    color: rgb(41 3 0);
    text-shadow: inherit;
    transition: 1.5s;
}

div:hover .button:hover .third {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

button:hover third {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: hi! could you please upload button Html code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `div:hover .button:hover`:

```css
div {
  background: #A2CCB6;
}
div button {
  background: #222;
  color: #f90;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}
div:hover button {
  background: #f90;
  color: #fff;
}
div button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <button>Hallo</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If You are using the selector class then the selector should be
> **.button** if you are styling by tag then you don't need to add **.button** just use **button**

```css
.third {
 color: red;
 text-shadow: inherit;
 transition: 1.5s;
 }
 button{
 background-color:black;
 padding:6px 10px;
 }
 button:hover {
 background-color:blue;
 }
button:hover .third {
color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<button><span class="third">Send</span></button>
```